# Deleting record on Continuous form in MS Access using acCmdDeleteRecord

Tags: ms-access, vba, delete-row

I have continuous form with just 2 fields and a button.

> Design View
>   [image: Form View]

'

> Form View
>   [image: Design View]

Below is the code for Delete Button.

```
Private Sub cmdDelete_Click()
     DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdDeleteRecord
     Debug.Print "IDWeb - " & Me.IDWeb
     'Here I Execute a Web API to Delete Data based on Me.IDWeb
End Sub
```

**The Problem** - Web API does not get the `Me.IDWeb Value` . SOme times the `IDWeb` is captured correctly, sometimes not.

*Edit1* : I tried the code below. But still the problem exists.

I guess the users can be on another record when they deleted the current record. Hence the issue. But the record is currently deleted in MS Access. Only the problem is `Me.IDWeb` is NOT captured correctly, and hence my web API is getting failed.

```
Private Sub cmdDelete_Click()
    Me.WebType.SetFocus
    If Me.IDWeb = "" Or Me.IDWeb = vbNull Or Me.IDWeb = vbNullString Then
        MsgBox "No Record Selected"
    Else
        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSelectRecord
        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdDeleteRecord
        Debug.Print "IDWeb - " & Me.IDWeb
        'Here I execute my Web API to Delete based on Me.IDWeb
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I suggest you **first** get `Me.IDWeb` (store it in a variable), **then** run `acCmdDeleteRecord`

Comment: @Andre Superb. Problem Solved. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to **first** get Me.IDWeb and store it in a variable,

then run `acCmdDeleteRecord` afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I don't use DoCmd. You are trying to get the IdWeb of a deleted record.
Assuming your IDWeb is a number (if not use the appropriate data type), the following should work

```
Dim lngIdWeb as long
lngIdWeb = nz(Me.IdWeb, 0)
If lngIdWeb > 0 Then
Me.RecordsetClone.FindFirst "IdWeb = " & lngIdWeb
If Not Me.RecordsetClone.NoMatch Then
Me.RecordsetClone.Delete
End If
Debug.Print "IdWeb - " & lngIdWeb
End If
```

Comment: Solved by @Andre Method (Mentioned in Comment of the Question). Thanks for your suggestion.